# Why does avrdude error appear when interfacing GLCD with arduino uno in ubuntu

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd, uploading, avrdude

I want to interface a GLCD with arduino uno. The GLCD is JHD12864E.   The connections are as shown in this image [image: GLCD Connections]

I downloaded the OpenGLCD library and uploaded HelloWorld program from it.
I got the error:
        stk500_recv() : programmer is not responding

Then I googled it and also tried to upload using ISP using another arduino. The program uploaded successfully, but i did not get any output on GLCD.

I am not getting this error when uploading any other sketches. Can anyone explain to me why do we get this error? And what is the solution to it?

Comment: Have you read the 'reset function note' here http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/GLCDks0108? It may desribe your problem.

Comment: @DaveP Yes i have followed it.